# Pulling a random word/string from a line in a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file that has six words on one line, I need to randomly generate a word from that line. The text file name is WordsForGames.txt. I am making a hangman game. This what I have so, far. I am a little lost please help

```
import random
import os
print(" Welcome to the HangMan game!!\n","You will have six guesses to get the answer correct, or you will loose!!!",)
words = open("../WordsForGames.txt")
```

Comment: sorry new user, so still getting use to the format

Comment: So all the words are on the first line? How does your file look like?

Comment: Yes all on one line with one space  in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `words = open("../WordsForGames.txt")` does not read the file, it just opens it for reading or possibly writing if you add additional flags.

You need to read the line or lines using `readlines()`, for example, and then most likely split the words into a list and then randomly select one of the words. Something like this:

```
import random 

# get the first line if this is the one with the words words
lines = open("../WordsForGames.txt").readlines() 
line = lines[0] 

words = line.split() 
myword = random.choice(words)
```

Comment: I tried your method too, and it works as well. I only had to change ,readline() to read() because I forgot that they were all on separate lines. I had to change line = lines[0] to line = line[0:] because of the fact they were on separate line. thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5):

It *could* be as simple as:

```
import random
print(random.choice(open("WordsForGames.txt").readline().split()))
```

The words are read from the first line of the file and converted into an array, then a random choice is made from that array.

If the words are instead on *separate* lines (or spread *across* lines), use `read()` instead of `readline()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can read a line from the file using `.readline()` function and then split the string into a list of strings, based on whatever delimiter you used for the the words in the line . And then `random.choice()` to randomly select one word from the list.

Another suggestion would be to use `with` statement for handling the file , so that `with` statement can handle closing the file automatically for you.

Example -

```
import random
with open("../WordsForGames.txt") as word_file:
    words = word_file.readline().split() #This splits by whitespace, if you used some other delimiter specify the delimiter here as an argument.
random_word = random.choice(words)
```

If the words are on  separate lines, you can use `.read()` instead of `.readline()` as (with rest of the above logic same) -

```
with open("../WordsForGames.txt") as word_file:
        words = word_file.read().split()
```

Comment: words = wordfile.readline().split() #This splits by whitespace, if you used some other delimiter

Comment: It just keeps pulling the first word that's it

Comment: Then that means that the words are all on separate lines? Instead of `.readline()` , try with `.read()` in the middle.

Comment: yes you are right I though I put them all on one line. it works beautifully, thanks a lot. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

shortest solution

```
import random
print(random.choice(open('file.txt').read().split()).strip())
```