# Program prints random letter instead of random word from remote directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the middle of creating Hangman game using remote directory.
I got stuck because program prints random letter instead of random word from the directory.

First:

```
directory = "http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt"
response = requests.get(directory)
text = response.text
```

When i am trying now to `print (text)`, it prints all words listed in the directory.

However, when I am reaching part, where i choose and print random word by:

```
SECRET_WORD = random.choice(text)
print (SECRET_WORD)
```

My output is just a random letter.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `response.text` is, surprise, _text_ - a stream of letters combined in some specific way. So, when you do the choosing, you get a random letter, not a random _word_.

Comment: Cannot comment This question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32773323/4180176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
directory = "http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt"
response = requests.get(directory)
text = response.text.split()
SECRET_WORD = random.choice(text)
print(SECRET_WORD)
```

Comment: It did the work, thanks! However, could you explain what split() did here?

Comment: it's splitting the stream of text (string) into a list... so now if you evaluate text, it will be ['words', 'morewords'] rather than 'words morewords'

you don't need to give a parameter to split in this case because it will find consecutive chars and that's how it knows where to split the words, in this case the consecutive chars is '\r\n'

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for digging deeper but i am still a newby, all knowledge is worth a lot and highly appreciated!