# Python | Import textile into a string, but always choose random word

Tags: python

There is a textfile, called "rockyou.txt" (it has a ton of different passwords in it).
I want to always pick a random word out of there, and put that one into a string. So it shouldn't be like:

```
with open("rockyou.txt") as pw:
    password = pw.readline()
    print(password)
```

because then it always just takes the first word out of the textfile, and not random ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773275/pulling-a-random-word-string-from-a-line-in-a-text-file-in-python 
i hope this will answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load everything into memory first, select a random index and then select the results:

```py
import random
with open("rockyou.txt") as pw:
    passwords = pw.readlines()
    randomly_selected_password = random.choice(passwords)
    print(randomly_selected_password)
```